# SQLite3: the database was created empty?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database with a table using sqlite3 on my C program, however the database is always created as empty, though it was created non-empty using the sqlite shell,
 here is my code below:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello\n");
    sqlite3 *sqdb;
    sqlite3_initialize();
    const char* db = "test";
    sqlite3_open(db, &sqdb);
    const char* stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable(creationdate DATE, data VARCHAR);";
    sqlite3_stmt *ppstmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqdb, stmt, -1, &ppstmt, 0)!=SQLITE_OK)printf("error!\n");
    sqlite3_finalize(ppstmt);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: A SQL database is always empty on creation.

Comment: the SQL database shall contain a table, so it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: It won't be empty after you add a table, but it's empty when you create it.  (Note that the most common cause for the "empty db" scenario is that you don't know where the db file is actually located.)

Comment: what do you mean by "is that you don't know where the db file is actually located"? the file is inside the directory of the program, and I'm viewing it as empty, unlike the other one created via sqlite shell that was non empty.

Comment: I mean, it's not in the directory you think it is.

Comment: the file is inside the same directory of the program, and I'm viewing it as empty(0kb), unlike the other one created via sqlite shell that was non empty(2kb).

Comment: And you're closing the file on exit?

Comment: it's all right now, my mistake here is that I was missing the sqlite3_step() call after the sqlite3_prepare_v2() one, also I forgot to call sqlite3_close() at the end, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   int main(void)
{
    printf("hello\n");
    sqlite3 *sqdb;
    int ret;
    sqlite3_initialize();
    const char* db = "test.sqlite3";
    sqlite3_open(db, &sqdb);
    const char* stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable(creationdate DATE, data VARCHAR);";
    sqlite3_stmt *ppstmt=NULL;

    ret=sqlite3_exec(sqdb,stmt,0,0,0);
    if(ret!=SQLITE_OK)printf("error!\n");
    else printf("Table added\n");
    sqlite3_finalize(ppstmt);
    sqlite3_close(sqdb);
    return 0;
}
```

Please do remember to close the DB after operation.

Answer (score 3):

`sqlite3_prepare_v2()` alone just compiles the SQL but does not run it. Call `sqlite3_step()` on the compiled statement to run it, or use `sqlite3_exec()` that combines prepare+step+finalize into one function call.